# Unable to set state variables during staging test on Goerli using Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, unittesting, goerli

I am able to set variables during my unit tests on the local Hardhat Node, however the same test fails on Goerli.

This is the code for my test:

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Whoopy Staging Tests", function () {
          let whoopy,
              deployer,
              player,
              cloneAddress,
              clonedContract,
              txReceipt,
              tx,
              accountConnectedClone,
              manager,
              create

          const chainId = network.config.chainId

          beforeEach(async function () {

            accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
            deployer = accounts[0]
            player = accounts[1]
            await deployments.fixture(["all"])

            const dir = path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "/Users/boss/hardhat-smartcontract-whoopy/artifacts/contracts/Whoopy.sol/Whoopy.json"
            )

            const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8")
            const json = JSON.parse(file)
            const abi = json.abi

            whoopy = await ethers.getContract("Whoopy", deployer)
            manager = await ethers.getContract("VRFv2SubscriptionManager", deployer)
            wf = await ethers.getContract("WhoopyFactory", deployer)

            tx = await (await wf.connect(player).createClone(player.address))
            txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)


            cloneAddress = await txReceipt.events[1].args._instance
            clonedContract = new ethers.Contract(cloneAddress, abi, player)
            accountConnectedClone = clonedContract.connect(player)
        })

        describe("Whoopy Tests", function () {
            beforeEach(async function () {
                create = await accountConnectedClone.createWhoopy(
                    "Test",
                    1,
                {
                    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10000000000000000", "wei"),
                    gasLimit: 3000000
                })
                console.log(create)
            })
            it("creates Whoopy correctly", async function () {

                const whoopyName = await accountConnectedClone.getWhoopyName()
                const num = await accountConnectedClone.getNum()

                expect(whoopyName).to.equal("Test")
                expect(num).to.equal(1)
            })
        })
```

Here is the function I am testing:

```
   function createWhoopy( //to be created only once 
        string memory s_whoopyName,
        uint256 s_num,
    ) public payable restricted {
        whoopyName = s_whoopyName;
        num = s_num;
}
```

Seems pretty straight forward but don't know why it's not working. My accounts have enough test eth. The test reverts as follows:

```
AssertionError: expected '' to equal 'Test'
      + expected - actual

      +Test
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was something stupid (as I thought it would be). I forgot to put `await create.wait(6)` which was needed to wait for the blocks to mine the transaction.

It went through on Hardhat because Hardhat mines blocks immediately, but since Goerli is a live Testnet you need to wait for the transaction to be mined.

Answer (score 0):

do you have mention of Goerli network in your hardhat.config.ts? if not try adding this to networks in your hardhat.config.ts `goerli: { url:` https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/${alchemyApiKey}`, accounts: {mnemonic: mnemonic} },`

Comment: yep! all set up. Ran a different test on goerli which worked, it's this one that doesn't seem to be working.